# Form Handling HTML with PHP/Python- Source code not being interpreted/Assistance with Configuration?

Tags: php, python, html, apache, cgi

I am working on a website and I would like to submit user input from a `<form>` to a separate webpage visible only to myself & co workers, while redirecting the user to a separate page. The info would be quite simple:

Name
Email
City
Country
Image

My form is as follows:

```
'<form id="contestEntries" method="POST" action="#" /> 
  <p>
    <input type="email" class="inputField" id="emailInput" name="emailInput" maxlength="25" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email" required />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="text" class="inputField" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" maxlength="15" placeholder="Name" required />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="text" class="inputField" id="cityInput" name="cityInput" maxlength="25" placeholder="City" required />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="file" id="attachImageInput" name="file" accept="image/*" required>
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
  </p>
</form>`
```

***Please note that I have omitted country input due to the length of the code, however this has tested functional***

Anyway- the problem that i am encountering is that my form will submit properly, and redirect to the appropriate file that is set to `action=""`

***My problem is that the php script I have set to read this user data does not render in the browser- I can only see the source code for the file where the input has been redirected. I tried using Python in place of PHP and the results are the same***

Now I understand that HTML and PHP/Python are interpreted differently, and that I need a web server to process the PHP/Python code- but so help me God this is impossible.

Can someone please help me understand where I have gone wrong? If possible I would like to test this locally, however all attempts to configure any server to process my scripts has been futile. I have tried XAAMP running Apache, and after 14+ hours of trying to troubleshoot I can't get Apache to run. (Tried re configuring .htdocs ports already; still not working)

Is there no simpler way to test my PHP or Python scripts? I am not opposed to running temporarily Public despite security concerns, i'm just desperate to get this up and running at this point. If someone can tell me how I can configure Bluehost to run PHP or Python scripts I would be forever in your debt.

Thanks!!

***EDIT: PHP script***

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["emailInput"];
$name = $_POST["nameInput"];
$city = $_POST["cityInput"];
$image = $_POST["imageAttachInput"];

echo $email;
echo $name;
echo $city;
echo $image;

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if page is not submitted to itself echo the form
?>
```

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with html or php since if sounds like your webserver not running is the problem. You should revise your question and consider posting it on server fault instead since it is not about coding.

Comment: Can you post some of the PHP code that handles the form and reads the $POST values. Also maybe an example name of the file that action="#" going to. I think there is some information missing about your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you need a web server of some sort.  PHP and Python scripts only run on web servers, not on clients/browsers.  If you don't have a web server installed on your Windows machine and your Linux server isn't configured properly (Apache not working), you're not going to be able to run it as a web application.

If you have PHP installed on a machine, you can always run it directly on that machine from the shell prompt to screen/console (ex. php -f filename.php) and that should at least show you if the script has proper syntax to be executed.  It will also send output to the screen and, while that won't render HTML nicely, you can always copy-and-paste the output into a text file on Windows and then open it in a browser to see that HTML output.  You wouldn't be able to test posting a web for to the script yet, but you could temporarily imitate that by adding values to it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Here is the PHP script:

Comment: Would you re-post the link?

Comment: Sorry- I edited the original submission to include the php script. I suspect that it is an issue with either my server configuration, or the configuration of my files via my host

Comment: Yeah, you can test that PHP script without a web server fully up and running if you have PHP installed somewhere.  Is it a Linux machine?  If so, just enter "php -f filename.php" at a system prompt (with the actual script name and path) and you should see whether it runs.  Once your web server is up, you can test it for real using a web browser.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my next question would be if I simply run the script from, say windows cmd.. it's able to pull data from the html file? I'm surprised I wouldn't need any special configuration for the html file for the php to process correctly. Like I don't need them in the same directory or anything? Thanks again! Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, if you run the PHP script from a Windows Cmd prompt, it will show you whether the script runs (or whether any errors) and at least some of the output.  It won't be a true portrayal of what it will be like when you run it in a web browser, but it will at least tell you if your PHP script is working.  Once you know that your PHP script appears to be working, then you know that you just need to get the web server (Apache) up and running and then you're in the home stretch.